Dokcer file with ubuntu 22 is not able to install numpy on it
I am trying to make a build from a dockerfile and in that process it needs to install numpy python package. It keeps running to some wierd error and m not able to get through numpy installation. Below is the details of my python package.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget tar python3.7 python3.7-dev libc-dev gcc make python3-pip build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libpq-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev redis-server
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
WORKDIR /ta-lib
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install setuptools==65.5.0
RUN pip install cython==0.29.37
RUN pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0
RUN pip install numpy==1.18.1

After running the above dockerfile i run into the issue below:
(Just posting the last part of the error)
119.5       error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
119.5       [end of output]
119.5   
119.5   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
119.5   ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
119.5 Failed to build numpy
119.5 ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried various options from the post of stackoverflow but none has worked so far.

Not a direct answer to your question: I wonder why you are using a very old & outdated python version? Would using the official python image based on Debian be simpler? I guess pip is using pip on python 2, you should write pip3.7 or use the whole path of the newly installed python.

The project i am on have some dependency which for now needs the old version of python. Since the updating to new python version is tedious process and it breaks most of the code in the project. We are slowly coming to latest python, going phase by phase so its taking longer. Untill then have to make work with this old version. Using python image gives issue on the psycopg related packages and hence using ubuntu image.

You seem to have deleted the interesting part of the error; can you [edit] the question to include more?  I'd also recommend using the Docker Hub image, FROM python:3.7 if you really need the old version.  That should be able to install prebuilt wheels which will be faster and avoid compilation issues like this.  It's secondary to your problem, but you might consider using pip freeze to generate a requirements file that you can install in one shot, rather than listing out individual packages in your Dockerfile.

@DavidMaze ah  yeah sorry about that. Because of the limit on text.....since the error was like really really long. Couldn't get all of it..so i just posted the last part of what i could. And yeah......actually i do have it and since i was facing some issue with numpy so had few pip install explicitly written so i could isolate the problem. I gotta use ubuntu coz of system level dependent of psycopg package. It needs to apt installation so it can work with python. Or else i could have used just that.

Installing a dead snake (Python 3.7) does not replace all python links (which is a good thing). Your pip commands use the system's python which is in case of Ubuntu 22.04 python 3.10 - and there is no binary of numpy 1.18.1 for python 3.10. Use pip3.7 and python3.7 as explicit commands, or create a virtual environment with
python3.7 -m venv ./venv3.7

and use pip / python from there (./venv3.7/bin/python, ./venv3.7/bin/pip)
P.S.: psycopg can be quite annoying, I know.

Right.....And yeah i will try this out though. And make sense..coz i remember that few years back i was able to build the image and as you said....this version of ubuntu doesnt have python 3.7...and the time when i had build the image successfully ti was some older version of ubuntu, atleast older than 22.04 for sure. Thank you this gives me some good insight.

But I would still rather go for the python 3.7 image and install the dependencies for psycopg there
